# Display List items in Combobox and Focus on presaved value from DB

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, ms-access-2010

i have an id textbox and a name, department combobox and a Division, i already linked them with MS Access, but the department and Division Comboboxes only show the selected value (not a list with all the items), i need it to give me a list with all the items and a Focus on the current Value for that ID.

This is what i have so far :

```
 private void id_txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            bool hasdata = false;
            if (id_edit.Text != "")
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                String query = " SELECT * FROM emp_personal WHERE ID = " + Int32.Parse(id_edit.Text) + "";
                command.CommandText = query;
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    hasdata = true;
                    name_edit.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(ds);

                    department_edit.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    department_edit.DisplayMember = "Department";
                    department_edit.ValueMember = "Department";


                    division_edit.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    division_edit.DisplayMember = "Division";
                    division_edit.ValueMember = "Division";
                }
                connection.Close();
            }

            if (!hasdata)
            {
                name_edit.Clear();
                department_edit.SelectedIndex = -1;
                division_edit.SelectedIndex = -1;

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution :

```
    while (reader.Read())
                {
                    hasdata = true;
                    name_edit.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
                    department_edit.Text = String.Empty;
                    department_edit.SelectedText = reader["Department"].ToString();
                    division_edit.Text = String.Empty;
                    division_edit.SelectedText = reader["Division"].ToString();
                }
```